# Use of make-array

Tags: clojure

Building a function in Clojure that returns a 2D matrix with all initial values set to zero, for which I intended to use make-array.

```
(def m (make-array Integer/TYPE 3 3))
```

however what I get in return isn't the instance of the array (expected [[0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0]]) but got `#object["[[I" 0x10014d2 "[[I@10014d2"]`.
I can properly access values in the m matrix via (get-in) and change them using (assoc-in), but ultimately I need to return the matrix, not the type of the object. Is there a way to do it?

PD. I'm new to stackoverflow and to Clojure.

Comment: Did you consider using [vectors](https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Vectors) instead of primitive integer arrays? Then you could initialize your matrix with `(def m (->> 0 (repeat 3) vec (repeat 3) vec))`

Comment: I'd use https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix in this case

Comment: That `[[I` tells you that it's a 2D integer array (that's how Java prints primitive array types), so you got exactly what you wanted. But yeah, unless you really need a 2D integer array, there are more convenient approaches in Clojure.

Comment: @Rulle. I thought it was more convenient to use make-array, but yes I can try using vectors. Still my question is, how can I return the actual array (not the address) built with make-array, if there is a way to do it?

Comment: @akond this is for a challenge, and I can't use core.matrix.

Comment: @Eugene Pakhamov Thanks, noted. In my case I do need an n-D integer array, where 'n' is a parameter of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really a matter of how your REPL is configured to display values. I get something similar in my REPL (launched with `lein repl`):

```
user=> (def m (make-array Integer/TYPE 3 3))
#'user/m
user=> m
#object["[[I" 0x4d632ca0 "[[I@4d632ca0"]
```

However, closer inspection shows that `m` is a Java array of Java integer arrays:

```
user=> (-> m class)
[[I
user=> (-> m class .getComponentType)
[I
user=> (-> m class .getComponentType .getComponentType)
int
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8391623/1008794) we can configure the repl to display values differently:

```
user=> (clojure.main/repl :print pprint)
user=> m
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

But you may consider representing your matrix with [vectors](https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Vectors) because they are immutable:

```
user=> (def m2 (reduce #(vec (repeat %2 %1)) 0 [3 3]))
#'user/m2
user=> m2
[[0 0 0] [0 0 0] [0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks Rulle, sorry I don't have enough 'reputation' to up-vote your answer.